# Aliased has_many_through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Say you're tracking rap artists.  I want to get a list of all the albums Weezy's contributed to so I use a `has_many_through` to get `albums` through `songs` and it works great!  Except it overrides `has_many :albums` which are *only* Weezy's own albums.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :albums, as: :featured_albums, through: :songs
  has_many :albums
```

Ideally I'd like to just create a name for it like `:featured_albums`.  Unfortunately the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Song
  has_many :albums
  ...
end

class Person
  has_many :songs
  has_many :featured_albums, through: :songs, source: :albums
  has_many :albums
  ...
end
```

I believe `:as` is used to specify that this is on the "poly" end of a polymorphic relationship.